# Sending email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I trying to send email in laravel using localhost but not receiving email in inbox neither in spam while it successfully send from laravel application not showing any error.
This is my controller funciton.

```
$user = $request->all();
Mail::send('emails.email', ['testVar' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('raja.waleed21@gmail.com', $user['doctor_firstname']);
    $m->to('raja.waleed21@gmail.com', $user['doctor_firstname']);
});
```

This is my email template.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {{  $testVar['doctor_firstname']  }}
    </body>
</html>
```

this is .env file setting.

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=raja.waleed2121@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

This is my `config/mail.php` file

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport'  => 'smtp',
            'host'       => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port'       => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
            'username'   => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password'   => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout'    => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path'      => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel'   => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name'    => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

what is the issue as I have not receiving email nor any error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you still have mailtrap in your env

Comment: MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io.. this one... what should be instead of this

Comment: you need to provide credentials from the SMTP service provider that you use in order to send mails. Is is mailgun you want to use?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question so that you're not showing your actual email address.

Comment: yes Dino I want to use mailgun

Comment: this is not the actuall email

Answer (score 0):

In your env, MAIL_MAILER is mailgun. So this line `'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),` firstly lookup env file, if mailgun is your driver, mailgun service require mailgun keys as seen as config/services.php so change MAIL_MAILER to smtp in .env file. Ps: i am using 465 port with ssl intead of tls

for mailgun

In .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=my.domain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=mYsE1cR3t
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.domain.com
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=MYAPP
```

In config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

In config/services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
    ],
```

Comment: AIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=raja.wed2121@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password.MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

Comment: this is what i changed but getting error "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"

Comment: If you want to use ssl, please enable openssl on your app server. I updated my answer for mailgun